# Find the largest number that Bash arithmetic can handle?

Tags: bash, arithmetic

How can I let my script determine the largest number for itself?

I looked through my environment variables, and I found these two that looked promising:

```
~# declare -p BASH_VERSINFO HOSTTYPE
declare -ar BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="5" [1]="0" [2]="11" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu")
declare -- HOSTTYPE="x86_64"
```

...but could I really trust parsing those, in order to draw a conclusion about what the largest number in Bash arithmetic would be?  There must be a better way, programmatically. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Similar question on SU](https://superuser.com/q/1030122/432690).

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski Thanks. But the accepted answer there is telling me how to play around with values like (2^31)-1 etc in order to figure it out interactively for myself... I was more like thinking better leave it to the script.

Comment: @patilan: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Cyrus You mean, upvote it? (Did you?) It's a cool answer. I refrained from accepting it just yet, because someone might come up with a brighter idea -- without a loop -- maybe like taking `-1` and just masking the most signifficant bit somehow.

Comment: @patilan, If you could use unsigned values, I think you could do `(int) ((unsigned) -1) >> 1)` in C. But since the shell uses signed numbers, the shift is arithmetic too, so that doesn't work. Other than shifting, I can't think how to get to the high bit without knowing the word length beforehand.

Comment: @ilkkachu Chicken and egg, right? :-)

Comment: @patilan, pretty much. Hence, you get to fall back to the loop. Though I guess for most cases you could assume it's either 32- or 64-bit signed numbers and just test those two. Except... well, ksh uses floating point. Not sure if it automatically switches between integers and floats, and with what rules. But it breaks the loop looking for an overflow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bash arithmetic uses signed numbers.

So the quick answer would be:

```
((MAX=(1<<63)-1))
```

But since you want your script to not know about the bitness of the system it's running on, then let's keep going.

Brute force would be, keep adding 1 in a loop, until you hit the point where it will overflow unto a negative number. But that could take years! :-)  A quicker and more elegant way to do it is with a simple bit-shift.

Let's find the sign bit, i.e., let's find the number that has `1` in the most signifficant bit, and zeros in all the other bits, however many they may  be. Once we have that number, we'll simply subtract `1` from it, and we'll get the largest signed number.

```bsh
# MIN -- the smallest signed number 0x8000...00  (it equals MAX+1)
# MAX -- the largest signed number  0x7Fff...FF  <-- what we are looking for

MIN=1; until (( (MIN<<=1) < 0 )) ;do :;done
((MAX=MIN-1))

echo $MAX

Result:
9223372036854775807
```

Or, here's a one-liner, without a loop.  We put the hex representation of a number in a variable, and then mask the sign bit through the variable expantion when passing it to the `printf` builtin:

```
printf -v MAX %x -1 && printf -v MAX %d 0x${MAX/f/7}

echo $MAX

Result:
9223372036854775807
```

On a machine with a different bitness than mine, the result will be a different number.

And just for illustration, in my case:

```
printf "MAX %X  %d\nMIN %X %d\n" $MAX $MAX $MIN $MIN
MAX 7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  9223372036854775807
MIN 8000000000000000 -9223372036854775808
```

A little side note about MIN: You may want to constrain yourself to using `((MIN=-MAX))`, otherwise you will occasionally run into problems with some arithmetic operations.

```
((MIN=-MAX)) ; printf "MIN %X %d\n" $MIN $MIN
MIN 8000000000000001 -9223372036854775807
```

Comment: It would take days?  A 64-bit count would take decades!  Assuming 1 count per clock cycle (e.g. for a compiled language like C on a normal modern CPU), counting up to 2^31 -1 takes about half a second at 4.2GHz, but counting up to 2^63 - 1 would take 69.6 years.  Maybe 35 years if you unroll the loop to do 2-per-clock increment / break-if-negative checks :P  (Bash arithmetic has vastly more overhead than 1/clock, so a day might be possible for 32-bit.)

Comment: Interestingly, on my 32-bit Bash I get the same result from both methods. Apparently, it uses `long long` for arithmetic.

Comment: "take years" part reminds me of [this](https://xkcd.com/303/).

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain the maximum number in a two-steps text-manipulation operation.

**TL; DR:** in `bash` all you need to do is:

```bsh
printf -v ff %x -1
printf -v max %d "0x${ff/#?/7}"
```

while the minimum can be obtained with the following additional operation:

```bsh
# this uses the shell's own arithmetic engine
min="$((max+1))"
```

To answer an OP's comment, note that `bash` implements `printf` as a builtin command, and by default it favors its builtin, hence it does not try to invoke the external `printf` command that is commonly available as a standalone executable under `$PATH`.

Also, the `bash`'s own builtin `printf` used as above does not spawn any additional process. It is instead run in the shell's current execution environment, therein creating the variables `$ff` and `$max` as specified with the convenient `-v` option.

---

The same as above but in a POSIX-compliant syntax would be:

```bsh
ff="$(printf %x -1)"
max="$(printf %d "0x7${ff#?}")"

# to obtain the minimum number in shells that only
# support integer numbers you can just do like
# said for `bash`
min="$((max+1))"

# else for shells defaulting to floating-point numbers
# (such as ksh93) you might instead do one text-manipulation
# operation on top of the arithmetic addition
min="$(printf -- -%u "$((max+1))")"
# of course such result would only apply to the shell's
# integer capacities, not to its floating-point capacities
```

Note that using the POSIX-compliant syntax above *may* spawn one (ephemeral) process for each of those Command Substitutions, and this is dependent on whether the particular shell optimizes simple `printf`s like those or not. However, even if the shell does spawn a process for each such `printf`, it does so by simply forking itself, hence it still relies on its own arithmetic capacities, not the ones of other arbitrary shells.

This is assuming that the shell implements `printf` as a *builtin*, like `bash` and many other shells do. A shell not implementing `printf` as builtin would use the external `printf` command available in `$PATH` (if any) which would yield valid results as far as the external `printf` command, the OS's C libraries, and the CPU's own capacities are concerned, but might not necessarily match the *shell's own* arithmetic capacity, such as is the case for `mksh` which uses 32-bit arithmetic even on 64-bit machines. Notably `mksh` might not implement `printf` as builtin or might anyway still prefer the external command, and `ash` from `busybox` might not implement `printf` as builtin if it hasn't been compiled in as such.

Comment: #LL3 I am afraid that if I shell out to an external `printf`, or if I spawn a whole different shell altogether, then I am not going to get the correct number for Bash arithmetic.

Comment: @patilan Indeed. You are probably commenting on the "Posixly" part. Else, if you want a correct answer to your question, which explicitly targets Bash, you have no reason to not use Bash builtins. All in all, this answer is quite good and deserves your upvote.

Comment: @patilan Not really. See my edit with expanded explanation (hopefully clear now).

Answer (score 3):

> I am sitting at a 64-bit machine, but how can I let my script determine that for itself?

Note that that's a separate question from what the largest numbers in bash arithmetic are.  You can't use this to figure out your machine's bitness, and the bitness of your machine doesn't determine Bash integer size.

**Bash numbers are always 64-bit, even on a 32-bit machine.**  (Or possibly wider, on an exotic machine where `long long` is wider than the ISO C required minimum of 64-bit.  It's maybe even possible that they could be one's complement or sign/magnitude (in which case you'd have
`min = -max`, instead of 2's complement `-max - 1`), if Bash is portable to C implementations that don't use 2's complement.  According to commenters, Bash uses `long long` and `unsigned long long` internally.  So that's something to keep in mind when designing run-time test methods.)

---

Just out of curiosity, I tested this on an old 32-bit Debian system kicking around with Bash 3.2.39.  LL3's method shows that `printf %x -1` prints 16 `f`s (so 8 bytes, 64 bits).

And I tested bash math with incrementing INT64_MAX wrapping to INT64_MIN

```
$ uname -a
Linux <non-updated kernel version hidden to protect the guilty> i686 GNU/Linux

$ echo $((9223372036854775807 + 1))
-9223372036854775808
```

So clearly Bash's source code uses `int64_t` or `long long` (or hopefully `uint64_t` to avoid C undefined behaviour when wrapping, unless they build with `gcc -fwrapv` to define that behaviour), not a type like `long` that's 32-bit on 32-bit machines.

Doing 64-bit addition on a 32-bit machine just makes the compiler use 2 instructions, like `add` + `adc` (add-with-carry), on machines that have a carry flag, or a 3rd instruction on machines like MIPS that don't.  So it's totally normal for languages to provide 64-bit types, and for higher-level languages that only have one type to use a nice wide type.

Comment: No, that's not the question! The point was to let the script figure it out. The script does not know or care how things are done under the hood.

Comment: @patilan: The point of my answer is that figuring it out won't tell you the bitness of your machine, which seemed to be the motivation or premise for your question.  I'm not trying to answer the other part of the question, about *how* to figure it out programmatically.  I'm just showing that that *if* you used those methods on a 32-bit build of bash, you'd get the same answer.  Maybe that should have been a comment, IDK.  (If all you really wanted to know was the max number bash math can use, then that's fine, but there's a reason I quoted the part of the question that I'm answering.)

Comment: @PeterCordes. Bash source uses `long long` and `unsigned long long`

Comment: @patilan: Oh, I think I misunderstood your phrasing.  You were guessing that a 64-bit machine would imply 64-bit bash math.  Not that you actually wanted to detect your machine's bitness.  So yes, that's a valid question.  But it's still interesting to know that the answer doesn't depend on the machine (except on exotic machines where `long long` is wider than 64-bit.)

Comment: 1. `uname -m` could be sufficient, no need for `-a` to then hide the version. 2. Bitness of the kernel doesn't define bitness of an executable. E.g. on my system the kernel is 64-bit, while almost all the userspace binaries are 32-bit. 3. Although a 32-bit kernel indeed can't run 64-bit programs, `uname` output will depend on personality (see `setarch(8)`), which can have been set globally (and is on my system, for compatibility with the 32-bit userspace). So it's not a good way to check. Instead, for your purpose, you may want to use `file $(echo $0)`.

Comment: @Ruslan, what system do you have that has a 64-bit kernel but a 32-bit userspace? I know they exist, but they impression they're rather rare.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes they are rare, I haven't seen any "official" distros with such a setup, although there seem to have been tutorials on how to achieve this in Debian. Mine is LFS so "your distro, your rules" applies ;) .

Comment: @Ruslan, ah ok. I've seen some arguments for the benefits of a [32-bit ABI on x86-64 (x32)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI), but got the impression it hadn't really taken off. (I remember Linux on UltraSPARC machines running 32-on-64, but that was a while ago...)

Comment: @ilkkachu ELF32-on-kernel64 is distinct from x32, which is based on ELF64. But both are nowadays mostly a historical curiosity: few distros (if any) support any of these setups officially (Debian does have an x32 port, but it's just a `chroot` kludge).

Comment: @Ruslan: The machine is a PIII 450MHz, overclocked to 500, from about 1999, before AMD64 was even invented. :P  (The software isn't quite that old, but that's why it's running 32-bit userspace.)

Comment: @ilkkachu: Re: 64-bit kernels for 32-bit user-space: I thought that was normal for i386 installs of "modern" distros, to let the kernel easily manage more than 4GB of RAM.  (Although even more modern is to not provide i386 at all.)  At least it was an option for Ubuntu and/or Debian; 64-bit kernels would show up in the package list for i386 systems, even without adding any multi-arch repositories.  I don't know what the installer would pick by default if you did a fresh 32-bit install on a 64-bit capable system; I never did that.